# Como receber o número de CPF e formatar para ficar sem os pontos e traço(Input Mask )

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-6, angular-5

Eu estou criando uma máscara com `inputMask`, mas o CPF é recebido assim: `222.222.488-19`.

E eu quero que ele tenha a máscara de no `input` mas na hora de enviar será sem os pontos e o traço. Tipo isso `22222248819`. Meu código:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <input [textMask]="{mask: mask}" [(ngModel)]="myModel" type="text"/>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public myModel = ''
  public mask = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    var variavel=$("#campo").val();//atribui o valor a variavel
    var variavel2 = variavel.replace('.', ''); //remove UM ponto
  var variavel2 = variave2.replace(',', ''); //remove UMA virgula
  var variavel2 = variave2.replace('-', ''); //remove UM traço
```

ABAIXO VAII EXPLICADO

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
  $('.cnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00', {reverse: true});
  $('.dinheiro').mask('000.000,00', {reverse: true});
 
 
$("#Botao").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault(e);

//Variavel com valor do campo dinheiro
var dinheiro=$("#dinheiro").val();
//retira o ponto coloca o restante em dinheiro 2.
var dinheiro2 = dinheiro.replace('.', '');
//retirar a virgula, e colocar o restante na dinheiro2.
var dinheiro2 = dinheiro2.replace(',', '');
//RECUPERAR VALORES do dinheiro.
alert(" O DINHEIRO COM MASCARA FOI : " +dinheiro+ " O DINHEIRO SEM MASCARA È: "+dinheiro2);
//Variavel com valor do campo cnpj
var cnpj=$("#cnpj").val();
var cnpj2 = cnpj.replace('.', '');
var cnpj2 = cnpj2.replace('.', '');
//*se tiver 1 ponto, dá um replace no ponto. se tiver 10... dá 10 replace.
var cnpj2 = cnpj2.replace('-', '');
var cnpj2 = cnpj2.replace('/', '');
//RECUPERAR VALORES do dinheiro.
alert(" O CNPJ COM MASCARA FOI : " +cnpj+ " O CNPJ SEM MASCARA È: "+cnpj2);

//Variavel com valor do campo CPF
var cpf=$("#cpf").val();
var cpf2 = cpf.replace('.', '');
var cpf2 = cpf2.replace('.', '');
//*se tiver 1 ponto, dá um replace no ponto. se tiver 10... dá 10 replace.
var cnpj2 = cnpj2.replace('-', '');
//RECUPERAR VALORES do dinheiro.
alert(" O CPF COM MASCARA FOI : " +cpf+ " O DO CPF SEM MASCARA È: "+cpf2);

})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<!-- ENTENDA OS CAMPOS PELO ID. é o id que vaos usar para recuperar os valores.-->
    <input class="dinheiro" id="dinheiro" placeholder="DIGITE UM VALOR EM DINHEIRO">
    <input class="cnpj" id="cnpj" placeholder="DIGITE UM CNPJ">
    <input class="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="DIGITE UM CPF">
   <br>
     <br>
       <br>
 PREENCHA TODOS OS CAMPOS E <br>
<button type="" id="Botao">CLIQUE AKI</button>
 <!-- PULE PARA O EVENTO JAVASCRIPT-->
```

Comment: Se isso resolve seu problema, marque como respondida.

Answer (score 2):

Cria uma função que remove esses caracteres usando regexp ali no mask. Por exemplo:

```
function somenteNumeros(cpf){
  let numeros = cpf.toString().replace(/\.|-/gm,'');
  if(numeros.length === 11)
   return numeros;

  return 'cpf inválido'
 }

 export class AppComponent {
   public myModel = ''
   public mask = somenteNumeros(cpf)
 }
```

se precisa fazer vários testes de regex, recomendo o site: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

Só pra complementar as respostas anteriores.
Se quiser tirar os dois de uma vez (ponto e traço). Minhas resposta está com JS Puro.

```js
let botao = document.querySelector("#botao");

botao.onclick = function() {
  let cpf_com_ponto_e_traco = document.querySelector("#cpf-com-ponto-e-traco").value;
  let cpf_sem_ponto_e_traco = cpf_com_ponto_e_traco.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace("-", "");

  console.log(cpf_sem_ponto_e_traco);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cpf-com-ponto-e-traco" value="111.222.333-44" readonly>
<button id="botao">Pegar CPF</button>
```

E uma outra alternativa para não ter que utilizar duas vezes o **replace** para tirar os dois primeiros pontos e outro replace para tirar o traço. Para isso utilizamos uma **expressão regular** no *primeiro parâmetro* do **replace** que só permite caracteres alfanuméricos naquela string. O que não for número, o **replace** troca pelo *segundo parâmetro*. **Veja:**

```js
let botao = document.querySelector("#botao");

botao.onclick = function() {
  let cpf_com_ponto_e_traco = document.querySelector("#cpf-com-ponto-e-traco").value;
  let cpf_sem_ponto_e_traco = cpf_com_ponto_e_traco.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

  console.log(cpf_sem_ponto_e_traco);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cpf-com-ponto-e-traco" value="111.222.333-44" readonly>
<button id="botao">Pegar CPF</button>
```

Comment: finalmente uma resposta com o codigo limpo e sem dependencia de bibliotecas nao citadas pelo OP, recomendo somente adaptar pro caso de cpf's com 2 replaces de ponto, porem muito bom. +1

Comment: Acredita que eu havia feito a resposta pensando em cep ? Mas eu já corrigi.

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma solução com *regex*, onde você não precisa ficar fazendo diversos *replaces*, ela ira capturar somente os dígitos em um *array* e converte-los em uma *string* com a função *join*.

**Exemplo:**

```js
let botao = document.querySelector("#botao");

botao.onclick = function() {

  let valorOriginal = document.querySelector("#cpf").value;
  let regex = /\d/g;
  let valorFiltrado = valorOriginal.match(regex);
  
  console.log(valorFiltrado.join(""));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cpf" value="455.666.727-99" readonly>
<button id="botao">Submit</button>
```

**Para aqueles que amam soluções em uma linha:**

```js
console.log("455.546.727-47".match(/\d/g).join(""));
```

**Explicação**

- Obtemos o valor do campo cpf com o query selector e atribuímos na variável `valorOriginal`
- Depois declaramos a variável regex com o valor `/\d/g`;
  O primeiro `/` mostra para o javascript que estamos declarando uma variável do tipo expressão regular
  O `\d` em seguida representa o que queremos capturar, um digito.
  Encerramos a declaração da regex com o `/`
  E por fim colocamos o `g`, sinalizando que essa regex deve percorrer toda a string.
- Em seguida vamos usar a função `match` para retornar o que a regex capturar como um Array.
- E para exibir o valor como uma string usamos a função `join("")`, ela vai retornar todos nossos valores em uma string sem separação por virgula, como faria normalmente se usássemos somente a função `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer diretamente no seu formulário antes de submetê-lo através do replace():

`formulario: FormGroup;
this.formulario.value.cpf = this.formulario.value.cpf.replace(/\.|-/gm,'');`

Obs.: considerando que seu formControlName="cpf".

Answer (score 0):

Em JS tem a função `replace()`.
Tu pode fazer algo tipo `cpfComMascara.replace("\D", "")`
Em regex `\d` significa dígito. A letra maiúscula é o contrário.
Logo, a regex vai substituir o que não for dígito por vazio.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cpf = '000.000.000-00';
var string = cpf.replace('.','').replace('-','').replace('.','') ;
```

Comment: joao, recomendo testar novamente sua resposta, ela nao responde a pergunta corretamente, atente-se no detalhe: mas na hora de enviar será sem os pontos e o traço. Tipo isso 22222248819...

Sua resposta retira somente 1 dos pontos.

Comment: editei a minha resposta @Paz

Comment: agora sim, as vezes esses detalhes pegam a gente.

Answer (score -3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
  $('.cnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00', {reverse: true});
  $('.dinheiro').mask('000.000,00', {reverse: true});
 
 
$("#Botao").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault(e);

//Variavel com valor do campo dinheiro
var dinheiro=$("#dinheiro").val();
//retira o ponto coloca o restante em dinheiro 2.
var dinheiro2 = dinheiro.replace('.', '');
//retirar a virgula, e colocar o restante na dinheiro2.
var dinheiro2 = dinheiro2.replace(',', '');
//RECUPERAR VALORES do dinheiro.
alert(" O DINHEIRO COM MASCARA FOI : " +dinheiro+ " O DINHEIRO SEM MASCARA È: "+dinheiro2);
//Variavel com valor do campo cnpj
var cnpj=$("#cnpj").val();
var cnpj2 = cnpj.replace('.', '');
var cnpj2 = cnpj2.replace('.', '');
//*se tiver 1 ponto, dá um replace no ponto. se tiver 10... dá 10 replace.
var cnpj2 = cnpj2.replace('-', '');
var cnpj2 = cnpj2.replace('/', '');
//RECUPERAR VALORES do dinheiro.
alert(" O CNPJ COM MASCARA FOI : " +cnpj+ " O CNPJ SEM MASCARA È: "+cnpj2);

//Variavel com valor do campo CPF
var cpf=$("#cpf").val();
var cpf2 = cpf.replace('.', '');
var cpf2 = cpf2.replace('.', '');
//*se tiver 1 ponto, dá um replace no ponto. se tiver 10... dá 10 replace.
var cnpj2 = cnpj2.replace('-', '');
//RECUPERAR VALORES do dinheiro.
alert(" O CPF COM MASCARA FOI : " +cpf+ " O DO CPF SEM MASCARA È: "+cpf2);

})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<!-- ENTENDA OS CAMPOS PELO ID. é o id que vaos usar para recuperar os valores.-->
    <input class="dinheiro" id="dinheiro" placeholder="DIGITE UM VALOR EM DINHEIRO">
    <input class="cnpj" id="cnpj" placeholder="DIGITE UM CNPJ">
    <input class="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="DIGITE UM CPF">
   <br>
     <br>
       <br>
 PREENCHA TODOS OS CAMPOS E <br>
<button type="" id="Botao">CLIQUE AKI</button>
 <!-- PULE PARA O EVENTO JAVASCRIPT-->
```

Answer (score -3):

cpf.replace(/\D/, '')
Ao invés de pegar, pega tudo que não é numero substitui por tudo que não é número por espaço vazio.